# How to download audio from a video streaming url in the Android SDK?

Tags: android, video-streaming

I need to create an app that allows me to download audio from a video stream in Android. What tools are there that allow me to do such a task?

Comment: Your English is hard to understand and i don't follow you.

Comment: i creating a simple app in that app i want to download a audio signal but the url is video streaming url like rtsp .its poosible to download audio signal from vedio link..