# Download audio from video sreaming url

Tags: android

I am listing online videos in my app and want to download only audio corresponding to that video. Is there any way to do it in android? I saw [How to download audio from a video streaming url in the Android SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553735/how-to-download-audio-from-a-video-streaming-url-in-the-android-sdk) but it is unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just download the audio from video file. In server you have to create separate audio file to download it. You can't just download audio from youtube unless they have audio file attached to it. You might have seen downloading audio from keepvid.com, but it does some work to extract audio from that url.

Comment: Never mentioned youtube. Does that mean there is no way to extract audio directly from video link? And is it possible on video present in SD card? I am not asking for any source code, but just hint like the class which let me do this.

Comment: As far as my experience, it is not possible. Will post in this, if I get any.

Comment: Regarding youtube, I just gave you a real world example.

Comment: As far as I know, we can't download even video from youtube.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203047/code-for-download-video-from-youtube-on-java-android. Check this out.

Comment: Thanks for posting but I read that already. But downloading from youtube is illegal.